# How to upsert a subdocument atomically?

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

I have a document structure for storing application related data for each user device. The company has some number of applications available, which is limited and not get changed so often. So I designed the document using embedded subdocument array approach to reduce seek and make it suitable for aggregation pipeline.

Let one document defined:

```
{
    _id: "device_unique_identification_code",
    device_model: "iPhone5,2",
    applications: [
        {
            app_id: "a_game",
            push_token: "edbca9078d6c0c3a9f17166bbcf5be440c8ed2c6",
            last_user_id: 132522
        },
        {
            app_id: "an_app",
            push_token: "fed949982ceac84279f22a29bdd66cc13b7750e1",
            last_user_id: 132522
        },
        {
            app_id: "yet_another_game",
            push_token: "5cbf5a2bf0db7d6d55bd454222844d37d4f351b6",
            last_user_id: 842452
        },
        {
            app_id: "yet_another_app",
            push_token: "d1b60db7d54246d55bd37f4f35d45c2284b5a2bf",
            last_user_id: 842452
        }
    ]
}
```

This collection only stores device-app specific data, all session/user related is kept in another collection.

Since those applications are quite busy, I must use atomic command to do anything to reduce the risk of race condition.

**Here is the question.**

**Given device "a" and application "b", store some device-app value (e.g., save a push_token) in a single atomic command.**

Here are the test cases.

- If there is no document of device "a", create one with device-app data.
- If the document of device "a" already exists, but there is no app "b". Push a new device-app.
- If the document of device "a" already exists and app "b" already exists. Update the existing one.

I wasted a few days trying various queries with upsert/addToSet/setOnInsert/etc. but still no clue.

PS. There are 2 more options I have thought about.

- Use separated collections, this will work but with the trade of seek performance and I am feeling like it's a kind of RDBMS.
- Use app_id as a map key to subdocument instead of array, this also works but I may loose the ability of aggregation pipeline and fallback to the (slower) map-reduce.

**Answer Described**

The solution is using optimistic locking with version field.

```
previousVersion = 0

while (true) {
    // find target document with current version number,
    // also create a new document with version 1 initially
    // also find whether there is an existing app_id
    // so we don't have to loop through the array
    doc = db.devices.findAndModify({
        query:{_id:"given_device_id"},
        update:{$setOnInsert:{version:1}},
        fields:{version:1,applications:{$elemMatch:{app_id:"given_app_id"}}},
        upsert:true,
        new:true})

    // prevent unexpected infinite loop
    if (previousVersion == doc['version']) {
        throw new InfiniteLoopExpectedException()
    }

    previousVersion = doc['version']

    if (doc contains applications) {
        // if document contains the target application
        // update it using $ positioning because I am too lazy to find the index
        result = db.devices.update(
            {
                _id:"given_device_id",
                version:doc['version'],
                "applications.app_id":"given_app_id"
            }, 
            {
                $inc:{version:1},
                $set:{"applications.$.push_token":"given_value"}
            })
    } else {
        // no app_id found ? simply push
        result = db.devices.update(
            {_id:"given_device_id",version:doc['version']},
            {
                $inc:{version:1},
                $push:{applications:{app_id:"given_app_id",push_token:"given_value"}}
            })
    }

    // if the update command failed, retry the process again
    if (result['nModified'] == 1) {
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [find and modify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)?

If you add a field `version` you can ensure that an update proceeds only against the version of the record that you have from a query (version). If it doesn't go through you can re-read the document (gets version n+m), increment the version (n+m+1), reapply your changes and retry `findandmodify` matching the version number you just read (n+m). Eventually you will succeed and when you do you know that no other thread or process intervened between your read and your write.

Comment: I totally forgot about optimistic locking, thank you for pointing it out. But, will this work for the first test case where there is no document in the first place? There is no version field to read then.